# как в nginx сделать вывод загруженной конфигурации

Tags: nginx

вопрос в том чтобы увидеть текущую кофигурацию из памяти, НЕ из файловой системы

Comment: а она должна отличаться?

Comment: @Дмытрык если её изменили/удалили и ещё не перезагрузили nginx, то может и отличаться

Comment: @andreymal, согласен. Абсолютно реально

Comment: При беглом гуглировании нашёл такой метод: https://gist.github.com/widnyana/e0cb041854b6e0c9e0d823b37994d343 (https://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process)  Проверил - вроде работает.